# Google map ignoring marker size for retina icons

Tags: size, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map driven by Advanced Custom Fields. I have created an iconType to dictate which icon is used as the marker depending on the custom field.

My marker images are 80px square but I want to force them to 40px square for retina reasons. I have tried lots of variations of code I've found via google etc but nothing works and the size gets ignored showing my markers at the larger 80px. My guess is because I have the 2 icons depending on iconType?

Can anyone help me force the size of these markers to 40px square please...

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));
var iconType = $marker.attr('data-icon');
var iconBase = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/';
var size = new google.maps.Size(40, 40);

if (iconType === 'Costa') {
    iconName = 'costa@2x.png';
} else {
    iconName = 'starbucks@2x.png';
}

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map,
    clickable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

    icon: iconBase + iconName,
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{
    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html()
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this recently, and I believe you'll need to use the new Icon object to specify your custom [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) properties, and use the `size` and `scaledSize` properties.  I fixed my issues following this guide:

[How to add retina ready pin marker to your Google maps?](http://www.minijus.lt/blog/uncategorized/how-to-add-retina-ready-pin-marker-to-your-google-maps/)